# How are the coefficients of the shifting nth root algorithm determined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been reading  about
the [nth root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_nth_root_algorithm), particularly the "Fourth root of $7$" section. I do not understand
where the value 600 comes from or what the coefficient values would be for larger values of N.

From that section the next digit D for 4th roots is the greatest value D such that $X \ge 4000Y^3D + 600Y^2 D^2 + 40YD^3 + D^4$, where X is the current portion of the radicand, Y is the previous extracted root value and D is the next
digit of the root.

If the next root (for an arbitrary integral N) digit were given by
$ N(10X)^{N-1}D + N(10X)^{N-2}D^2 ... D^N$ (that is multiplying by $N10^{N-1}$ through $N10$ — with the $600$ being $400$
in the $4$th root position I question — the multiplier values would make sense but that is not the pattern.

So what is the pattern for such pencil-and-paper algorithms for extracting roots digit-by-digit? Hopefully simply explaining the value $600$ in the $4$th root
would be enough for me to understand the greater pattern.

arithmetic

Share
Edit

Delete
Flag

asked 5 mins ago

avatar/a7872c871b0431b72df6350dd0394bea

SoronelHaetir
169   1 bronze badge

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: I am blind and have a difficult enough time just reading MathJAX (regardless of tools that are supposed to help), writing it is even harder.

Comment: Thank you, it was expanding (10y+d)^n that I was overlooking, once I actually multiplied that out for N=4 it does make sense. Particularly that when going from (100y^2 + 20yd + d^2)^2 and then the nine intermediate products of that expression that there are three values that contribute to the 600y^2d^2 that was confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern comes from the binomial expansion of `(10Y+D)^n`. For the case of `n=4`, the expansion of `(10Y+D)^4` would be `D^4 + 40 D^3 Y + 600 D^2 Y^2 + 4000 D Y^3 + 10000(Y^4)` [(from Wolframalpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binomial%20expansion%20of%20%2810Y%2BD%29%5E4).

To simplify things, search for the Pascal's triangle. For the case of `n=4`, look at the fourth row of the triangle. That's where the 6 in 600 comes from. From there you can construct the "formula" for other n's.

Now you might ask why `10000(Y^4)` is not computed in the "formula". This is because you will subtract the "formula" to the **remainders** instead of the X itself. Remember that Y is the root digit/s extracted thus far, so `10000(Y^4)` represents the "attempt" of Y (no D yet) to approximate X.